# Pulling data from github constantly

Tags: github

I'm new to programmming and I'm trying to fetch data from this dataset to display in a website about Corona Virus. This is the github repo:

https://github.com/CSSEGISandData/COVID-19/tree/master/csse_covid_19_data/csse_covid_19_daily_reports

How can I programmatically fetch data from Github and keep my website updated? What solutions are commonly used for real projects?

Comment: use covid-data-api (its on pip) this scrapes the johnhopkins dataset and  allows you to pass in a flag that tells it to regenerate daily (`force_update=False`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can clone the git repo into a folder and then run `git pull` daily with cron:

```
0 14 * * * cd /path/to/your/repo && git pull >/dev/null 2>&1
```

(at 2pm everyday in this example)